# Nested deferred in a YDN-DB transaction

Tags: javascript, deferred, ydn-db

I have looked at the example posted here: [YDN-DB with multiple deferred](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19087609/ydn-db-with-multiple-deferred) which contains some code that is very close to what I want, but not quite.

I am wondering if it is safe to nest deferred queries in a transaction? For example:

```
loadWorkOrders: function() {

        var params = {
            userId: 1,
            status: Status.Allocated
        };

        var allOrders = null;

        return workOrderHttpService.getWorkOrders(params).then(function(orders) {
            allOrders = orders.data;
            return ydndatabase.open();
        }).then(function(db){
                return db.run(function(runDb){
                    allOrders.forEach(function(workOrder){
                        runDb.count(Store.WorkOrder, ydn.db.KeyRange.only(workOrder.id)).then(function(count) {
                            if(count == 0) {
                                return runDb.put(Store.WorkOrder, workOrder);
                            } else {
                                return workOrder;
                            }
                        });
                    });
                }, [Store.WorkOrder], TransactionType.ReadWrite)
            });

    }
```

EDIT: I have edited the code to show how it is preceded by an async call to an http service

Comment: [Don't create a deferred](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/wiki/Promise-anti-patterns#the-deferred-anti-pattern) to tell when your `req` promise has resolved, you already have a promise!!!

Comment: Ah good point yes thankyou. (This is still prototype code hacked together very quickly) However, the question still stands.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are using it right. As @Bergi said, you can just return the `run` request.

It is safe to nest deferred as long as your promises are resolved synchronously or using db promises (always asynchronous).

Nesting deferred is generally fine, looping is to be worry about, such as `orders.forEach` for unexpected large loop. Browsers are not happy with long transaction (yes, can cause mysterious error or crash).

Like the way using count to check for record existance. I think it should be `ydn.db.KeyRange.only(workOrder.id)`, since `count` require a key range input argument.

Comment: Many thanks for that.....  but re: returning the run request i can't because I actually simplified the code in order to post it here. In the real code the service that returns the original list of orders returns a promise so the code above is wrapped in another then().

Comment: This is OT but Just realised that I probably need to be chaining promises instead of nesting them.

Comment: No. looping will run faster.

Comment: Sorry... actually the above code does not work. Doing ydn.db.KeyRange.only(workOrder.id) works but then each runDb.put gives out the following error: "Uncaught TransactionInactiveError: Failed to execute 'put' on 'IDBObjectStore': The transaction is not active."

Comment: I have edited the code to show how it is preceded by an async call to an http service. Should this make any difference?

Comment: what you show here is fine. You should not get any error. What is the size of orders? smaller size also cause error?

Comment: At the moment I am only testing it with 10 orders. I have to admit I didn't expect it to work, thats why I asked the question in the first place. Seeing as all IndexedDB calls are async I don't understand how the transaction knows to stay open. I can see it might stay open long enough to register the "counts", but by the time the "puts" are executed why would it still be open? (I realise this is probably just a lack of knowledge on my part!)

Comment: Yes, transaction is still active. I see. Return statement on put is wrong. It is not necessary.

Comment: I've just tried removing the return statement.. but same problem.

Comment: You mean the else { return workOrder; }? If so.. yes I have already removed that.

Comment: Yes. Should no problem now.

Comment: I am starting to think there is an incorrect version of the library available for download. As well as the problem above I have 2 other problems: (1) The addEventListener('ready', fn) function does not exist. (2) I am getting the same var is not defined error when I use db.get(Store.WorkOrder,1) as mentioned in the comments here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19203164/ydn-db-how-to-verify-if-a-record-exists/19204459#19204459